# Angular 5 $http polling with RXJS

Tags: rxjs, angular5, polling

I'm trying to create a polling service and this is what I have achieved.
The goal is to have a polling which can be stopped when response contains a certain value (e.g. `running: false`)

```
// Sample call
  _getData(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next({ data: "bar", running: true });
      }, 2000)
    })
  }

  start() {
    timer(0, 5000)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(() => from(this._getData())
        .pipe(map(response => response))
        )
      )
     // .pipe(filter(backendData => backendData.running === true))
      .subscribe(() => console.info("CIAO" + ++calls))
  }
```

The problem is that this fires once.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `concatMap` waits until its inner Observable completes.

In your `_getData` you return `new Observable` and then call `next()` yourself but you never call `complete()` so the Observable remains opened. Then `concatMap` will never call its project method again because it's waiting for the previous Observable to complete.

Comment: oops. I forgot the complete, what a fool. Thanks a lot.